# TabControl bound to List : ContentTemplate with UserControl not binding correctly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a `TabControl` with its `ItemSource` bound to a list.  The `ContentTemplate` of the `TabControl` is set to a `UserControl`, with the `UserControl`'s `DataContext` bound to item of the list.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Consoles}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedConsole}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:Console DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

It is working in that I get a tab for each item in the list and the `UserControl` is being displayed, but the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` is never being set.

If I place the `UserControl` outside the `TabControl` and Bind the `DataContext` then everything works as expected.  What Am I doing wrong with the `TabControl`?

Comment: Try removing `DataContext="{Binding}"`.  You should never have to do that in DataTemplates.  The value of the DataContext automatically flows down the visual tree.

Comment: That's there from me throwing stuff at it trying to make something work. I originally wrote the xaml without it and it isn't working that way either.

Comment: You should never have to do that in a DataTemplate.  Never.  Never ever.  Period.  Never.  Are you doing weird stuff in that UC?  Like UI work in a view model created for it?  Smells like it.  That, and cat litter.  Create a prototype and test my claim. Be shocked.  You might want to try examining the binding with Snoop during runtime.  Might give you some hints.

Comment: I have absolutely no code-behind anywhere in this project yet, everything is in viewmodel classes and xaml.  The viewmodels don't touch the UI at all.  The only slightly "odd" thing about the viewmodel for the user control is that it has a private reference to an object that raises events on a separate thread that it subscribes to. It uses the Application's dispatcher to move the processing to the UI thread.  I've disabled the timer though, and it still isn't picking up the datacontext.

Comment: All Snoop (and other inspectors) show me is that the user control still has the reference to the empty ViewModel created for design time support, not the one from the list the tab control is bound to.

Comment: Finally found it. I forgot to prefix the user control's DataContext in xaml with the "d:" namespace. When wpf inflated the xaml it was overwriting the binding with the hard-coded xaml value.  Thanks for leading me down the right path.

Comment: Hah, that sucks!  You can thank me by adding details about what was going on below in an answer.  I might find myself in the same situation, wondering what the hell is going on.  Congrats.

Comment: I'll write it up later tonight when I have some time.  What I find really surprising is that it worked perfectly when the user control wasn't in inside the TabControl's template.